# Cómo firmar un XML sin saltos de línea ni espacios en blanco?

Tags: java, xml

Estoy trabajando la con facturación electrónica de México, y para cancelar una factura se tiene que mandar un xml firmado con el certificado.cer y la llave.key, el problema es que al firmar el XML este se genera con saltos de linea.

si yo quito esos saltos de linea después de firmar el XML, el sello se vuelve inválido.

y si envio el xml con los saltos de linea me responden con un error generado por los saltos de linea.

**Este es el codigo con el que genero la firma**

***la firma la estoy generando con la API de javax.xml.crypto**

```
XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

    Reference ref = fac.newReference("", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
            Collections.singletonList(fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null)),
            null, null);

    SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE,
            (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
            fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null),
            Collections.singletonList(ref));


    X509Certificate cert = KeyLoaderFactory.createInstance(KeyLoaderEnumeration.PUBLIC_KEY_LOADER, new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Arturo\\Desktop\\PEMS\\Certificado\\00001000000201052508s.cer")).getKey();

    KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
    List x509Content = new ArrayList();

    X509IssuerSerial issuer = kif.newX509IssuerSerial(cert.getIssuerDN().getName(), cert.getSerialNumber());
    x509Content.add(issuer);
    x509Content.add(cert);
    X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);
    KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Arturo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\AdminFraccionamientoWeb1\\web\\assets\\Pdfs\\Cancel_" + UUID + ".xml"));

    PrivateKey privateKey = KeyLoaderFactory.createInstance(KeyLoaderEnumeration.PRIVATE_KEY_LOADER, new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Arturo\\Desktop\\PEMS\\Certificado\\DST1010185B7_1205102226S.key"), "Soporte1").getKey();

    DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, doc.getDocumentElement());

    XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);

    signature.sign(dsc);
    String Ruta = "C:\\Users\\Arturo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\AdminFraccionamientoWeb1\\web\\assets\\Pdfs\\Cancel_signed" + UUID + ".xml";

    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(Ruta);
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
    trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
```

aquí está el XML que me genera este código

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>  
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>    
<Reference URI="">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/> </Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>DiLnrOczxtHVnhG4EA9zj0JM8O0=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>PrHxWCpnZlFi92ETs0JMnVML/FoUxQkktRT5UpU9W90DhKZFX31nFjwEtt3GBluz+xEdt+j4lmnd
JHdZbEynVwqsm5ZF2Y/Z34fn/f050pUXyjitlog8QWoKB+oCbaNW1L3+9VHyuKQ4t/1XbNt6RCgM
RkDEm4hDc6V55G/szIQ=
</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<X509Data>
<X509IssuerSerial>   
<X509IssuerName>OID.1.2.840.113549.1.9.2=Responsable: Cecilia Guillermina García   Guerra, OID.2.5.4.45=SAT970701NN3, L=Cuauhtémoc, ST=Distrito Federal, C=MX,   OID.2.5.4.17=06300, STREET="Av. Hidalgo 77, Col. Guerrero",   EMAILADDRESS=asisnet@sat.gob.mx, OU=Administración de Seguridad de la   Información, O=Servicio de Administración Tributaria, CN=A.C. del Servicio de   Administración Tributaria
</X509IssuerName>   
<X509SerialNumber>275106190557734483187066766774039086286478061624
</X509SerialNumber>
</X509IssuerSerial>  
<X509Certificate>
MIIErTCCA5WgAwIBAgIUMDAwMDEwMDAwMDAyMDEwNTI1MDgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwggGVMTgw
NgYDVQQDDC9BLkMuIGRlbCBTZXJ2aWNpbyBkZSBBZG1pbmlzdHJhY2nDs24gVHJpYnV0YXJpYTEv
MC0GA1UECgwmU2VydmljaW8gZGUgQWRtaW5pc3RyYWNpw7NuIFRyaWJ1dGFyaWExODA2BgNVBAsM
L0FkbWluaXN0cmFjacOzbiBkZSBTZWd1cmlkYWQgZGUgbGEgSW5mb3JtYWNpw7NuMSEwHwYJKoZI
hvcNAQkBFhJhc2lzbmV0QHNhdC5nb2IubXgxJjAkBgNVBAkMHUF2LiBIaWRhbGdvIDc3LCBDb2wu
IEd1ZXJyZXJvMQ4wDAYREVMRDAUwNjMwMDELMAkGA1UEBhMCTVgxGTAXBgNVBAgMEERpc3RyaXRv
IEZlZGVyYWwxFDASBgNVBAcMC0N1YXVodMOpbW9jMRUwEwYDVQQtEwxTYYQ5NzA3MDFOTjMxPjA8
BgkqhkiG9w0BCQIML1Jlc3BvbnNhYmxlOiBDZWNpbGlhIEd1aWxsZXJtaW5hIEdhcmPDrWEgR3Vl
cnJhMB4XDTEyMDUxMTAzMzYyNloXDTE2MDUxMTAzMzYyNlowge4xMDAuBgNVBAMTJ0RFU0FSUk9M
TE9TIFkgU09MVUNJT05FUyBFTiBUSSBTQSBEIUJGVjEwMC4GA1UEKRMnREVTQVJST0xMT1MgWSBT
T0xVQ0lPTkVTIEVGFERLIFNBIERFIENWMTAwLgYDVQQKEydERVNBUlJPTExPUyBZIFNPTFVDSU9O
RVMgRU4gVEkgU0EgREUgQ1YxJTAjBgNVBC0THERTVDEwMTAxODVCNyAvIFJJSk82OTA1MDhUQzEx
HjAcBgNVBAUTFSAvIFJJWEo2OTA1MDhIWlNTWFIwNjEPMA0GA1UECxMGVW5pZGFkMIGfMA0GCSqG
SIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDQZhQqxDy8Z05TPsl+jWl02mufOmhO2gyfQ2fNyCdbdjDDX3Ro
yp/23TYv6GiITJrsnUrEgDN6WrFIyS906GvyUvzQ8yTDwJPcS3PPLeybKr45PQIs06pyX70bNCEa
hJE3Afx+0YxfgQcw4QuSJ3Gr0mQT1A7/N0Ol33iQgtTLeQIDAQABox0wGzAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAA
MAsGA1UdDwQEAwIGwDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAbkjSi+DlMH69RK7fFXDLvZYUX+4gvutp
X2ex4LU/qFZVw7lvIYWITeUqF2DmuRzNXKNQqgSSRwuOnU0/ipxjR9JL0JIlLgy71nMtwMyQUO8q
Ei/EihXg1XHtOvPSsnFigRunD8ziyDpz+2ozUZS969zjRbsve9J5J2ke3CirrIjOLQaYbWBngrdl
8pXJPaaElkB5ZwzRKAP94P14WPOioTSmkBbhChEJ6xZKFcDRySRfWAsXmss9CvBM3nMqPhFdw2kj
6Rr/NsST5PZtp5Olk1xBhrPj5MVTZmzLpDvTz6+wFwrn5ucrIkUL+Uk4ZGD0HnTZYEeCh+VPeyXe
Er5fAw==
</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

Como se puede observar el xml que se genero tiene los saltos de linea (no deseados).

Agradecería cualquier ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Después de unas cuantas horas investigando encontré la solución a mi problema
espero le sirva de algo a alguien.

Simplemente tenemos que asignarle el valor `true` a el parámetro `ignoreLineBreaks` pues por default su valor es `false` lo que permite que a la hora de firmar un documento XML la añada saltos de linea.

Aquí el código para evitar que se añadan los saltos de linea:

```
Field f = XMLUtils.class.getDeclaredField("ignoreLineBreaks");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(null, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Y después podemos comprobar que se haya asignado el valor correctamente con la siguiente linea:

```
System.err.println(XMLUtils.ignoreLineBreaks());
```

Comment: Tal vez quieres agregar la siguiente propiedad a la JVM: `-Dcom.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.ignoreLineBreaks=true`. O quizás `System.setProperty("org.apache.xml.security.ignoreLineBreaks", "true");`.

Comment: Cualquier de los dos, en lugar de utilizar la [*Reflection API*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) para *configurar* ese valor.

Comment: Desafortunadamente ninguna de la dos opciones que me sugieres funcionaron.

Comment: Disculpa estoy con el tema de cancelación de Factura, podrias ayudarme con las clases que utilizas para la firma, por que al crear la mía me arroja un error de que no es válida la firma, o en su defecto proporcionarme una pagina de validador de firma con XML.

Answer (score 3):

Trata usando la propiedad [**`OutputKeys.INDENT`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html):

```java
 Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
 trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
```

> [**`INDENT`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html#INDENT): especifica si el transformador puede agregar espacio en blanco adicional cuando se emita el árbol de resultados; el valor debe ser "`yes`" o "`no`".

Comment: ¿Java 1.4? Estamos en el año 2016 con Java 7 depreciado, Java 8 en todo su esplandor y Java 9 muy cerca.

Comment: Gracias por responder Elenasys, pero ya probe la propiedead IDENT y no funciona, pues sigue generando el XML con saltos de linea.